# Is the m2eclipse mailing list being managed?

Tags: m2eclipse, mailing-list

I tried to subscribe to the m2eclipse mailing list by sending an email to user-subscribe@m2eclipse.codehaus.org but it never sent me back any confirmation email.  I sent an email to info@sonatype.com asking if the mailing list was still running a couple of weeks ago and haven't received any response back to that either.

Then I found another way to subscribe via http://xircles.codehaus.org/lists/info/search. So I did and am now receiving emails sent to the list.  However, I can't send the list emails.  They get bounced back with a failure notice:

```
Hi. This is the qmail-send program at mail.codehaus.org.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<user@m2eclipse.codehaus.org>:
Sorry, only subscribers may post. If you are a subscriber, please forward this 
message to user-owner@m2eclipse.codehaus.org to get your new address included. (#5.7.2)
```

I've forwarded this message as instructed twice now (once yesterday and once this morning) without result so far.

Does anyone know if this mailing list is being managed?  It sucks to be only able to read messages and not to send them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mailing list has now been moved from codehaus to Sonatype.  See http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/project-information.html for subscribe info.